# Bamboo Specs - Permissions issue creating a deployment plan

Tags: java, bamboo, bamboo-specs

I'm trying to create a deployment plan by command line from mi bamboo specs in java. When I'm trying to create it I get a permission error saying that I don't have permission to create the deployment plan. If I try to create the deployment plan manually through the browser I can do it without problems using the same user.

As info, my user has project admin permissions, and the token created to use in the bamboo spec was created with the option to have the same privileges as the user.

The error is the following:

"*Execution default-cli of goal com.atlassian.bamboo:bamboo-specs-runner:8.0.5:run failed: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: An error occurred while publishing deployment CAP-NEWBETEST: **You don''t have CREATE permission to import deployment project**. -> [Help 1]*"

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9XnQ.png)

Is there any way to be able to create the deployment plan directly from bamboo specs?

The bamboo version I'm using is: **8.0.5 build 80013**

**Code:** https://github.com/paruuy/bamboo-specs-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does it work as expected for username\password pair at .credentials file?

Comment: Hi @OleksiyChystoprudov thank you for the answer but I also tried with the .credential file and I have the same error that using a token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to the Atlassian technical team my problem is having a user with project admin permissions. Having global admin permission in my user it is possible to create a deployment plan.